# React: setCookie hook doesn't set any cookie

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, react-cookie

I'm trying to integrate Auth0 to my SPA. I'm embedding the Lock feature, so it handles authentication by itself.

I can login, and the Lock feature works fine, however I'm trying to save the `accessToken` and the `idToken` returned by Lock to a cookie. I'm using `react-cookie` for that.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Auth0Lock from "auth0-lock";
import AUTH_CONFIG from "../../config/auth0";
import moment from "moment";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import history from "../../utils/history";

export default function Lock() {
    const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies(["token"]);

    const lock = new Auth0Lock(AUTH_CONFIG.clientId, AUTH_CONFIG.domain, {
        auth: {
            responseType: "token id_token",
            sso: false
        },
        container: AUTH_CONFIG.container,
        theme: {
            primaryColor: "#3a99d8"
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (cookies.token && cookies.token.expires < moment()._d) {
            history.push("/");
        }
        lock.show();
    }, [cookies]);

    lock.on("authenticated", authResult => {
        let expiresAt = moment(
            authResult.expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime()
        );
        setCookie(
            "token",
            {
                access_token: authResult.accessToken,
                id_token: authResult.idToken
            },
            { path: "/", expires: expiresAt._d, secure: true }
        );
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <div id={AUTH_CONFIG.container} style={{ marginTop: "32px" }} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

So, after authenticating, the `lock.on` event listener is called. I can see that it works fine, however the `setCookie` hook doesn't save the cookie. I've already `console.log(authResult)` and can confirm that it returns the appropriate values, but the `setCookie` doesn't save anything. Exploring my browser storage, I can see that no cookie is saved.

Does anybody have a clue why it doesn't save the `token` cookie?

Thanks in advance

Edit: I found the issue. I was setting `secure: true`, however I was trying to access it thru `http://localhost`, which is not secure.